# How to move a search input field (filter) in Search API module to different region (Drupal 7)?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-theming

I have a Search page I made with Search API with filter input field and facets. All this stuff is displayed in Content region, but I need a search line to be moved to Top Bar region. Is there's a way to split up the module into a two regions?

Please no hard code - I'm not strong with PHP and this is my first Drupal site. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Already figured out how to do that.

Just set "Exposed form in block" to "Yes" when editing a view, and then you can freely move the block with exposed filter to any region in Blocks.